# cant set fancybox iframe from javascript

Tags: javascript, fancybox-3

I am trying to set and call fancybox from within javascrip like this

```
$.fancybox.open({
        type : 'iframe',
        'width'             : '75%',
        'height'            : '75%',
        'autoScale'         : false,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        src : url,
        smallBtn : false,
        fitToView: false,
        autoSize: false,
        autoDimensions: false
  })
```

It opens it fine but does not define the sizes, what am I doing wrong? o i need to set something else up? It just loads a page that displays a map, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use either CSS or `iframe.css` option:

```
    iframe : {
        css : {
            width  : '75%',
            height : '75%'
        }
    }
```

See docs - https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#iframe - for more info.